# Issue with attempting to create a d3 sunburst visualisation

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

First off, apologies as I am new to this. I have been trying to modify Kerryrodden's sunburst that appears here:

http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

[image]

I am trying to modify the code to work with a .json file rather than a .csv file. I thought this would be straight forward but I have come across problems. Attached below is the .js file and the .json file I have created.

Any help with these would be much appreciated

Regards

**sequence.js**

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {
  "june11": "#5687d1",
  "atts": "#7b615c",
  "jo": "#de783b",
  "sus1": "#6ab975",
  "sus5": "#a173d1",
  "sus9": "#8A2BE2",
  "sus13": "#5F9EA0",
  "early": "#008B8B",
  "jcp": "#FF1493",
  "jcpaft": "#B22222",
  "stillon": "#FFFFF0",
  "allsus": "#7CFC00",
  "nosus": "#9ACD32"
};

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, json) {
createVisualization(json);
});

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization() {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

    var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };


// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}
```

**cohorts2.json**

```
{
 "name": "ref",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "june11",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "atts",
         "children": [
          {"name": "early", "size": 11},
          {"name": "jcp", "size": 40},
          {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 50},
          {"name": "stillon", "size": 195},
          {"name": "jo",

             "children": [
              {"name": "early",  "size": 100},
              {"name": "jcp", "size": 67},
              {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 110},
                 {"name": "stillon", "size": 154},

               {"name": "sus1",      
                "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 11},
                    {"name": "jcp", "size": 118},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 39},
                      {"name": "stillon", "size": 2779}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus5",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 0},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 64},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 410},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 82}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus9",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 1018},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 3458},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 106},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 243}
                  ]
                },

               {"name": "sus13",
                 "children": [
                  {"name": "early",  "size": 110},
                  {"name": "jcp", "size": 190},
                  {"name": "jcpaft", "size": 80},
                     {"name": "stillon", "size": 9190},
                     {"name": "allsus", "size": 3970}
                     ]
                    }

                 ]
              }
         ]
        },

      {"name": "noatt", "size": 30}
    ]
    }

 ]
}
```

Comment: sorry to ask that but why don't you just use the example by Mike Bostock that uses .json files? It's here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I started using the partition one you linked to (mainly to make sure my .json file was correct) but I was after the functionality of kerryroddens's.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what JSON format is required is to simply print the variable that contains all the data in the original file to the console. This will show you exactly what format you need.

Comment: if you need to color code the "early" "jcp" and other recurring values, that could be done fairly easily if you want to, the color in the example is dependant on the hierarchy if i'm not mistaking

Answer (score 0):

It turns out is really easy. You just use this code:

```
d3.json(<path to your file cohorts2.json>, function(error, json) {
    createVisualization(json);
});
```

instead of whatever is correspondent code in original example.

I even made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbZ3S/) that shows what is achieved with that code: *(note that you need to fix legend and coloring, since they were 'hardcoded' in original example; also jsfiddle doesn't allow usage of json files, so I just used javascript variable instead, but the effects should be exactly the same)*

[image]